# Troubles with using GROUP BY in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to write a propper SQL query in MS SQL Server. 
First of all, i have the following tables: Towns, Employees, Addresses. Almost every employee has Manager, whom ManagerID is foreign key in Employees also. (Self relation). My goal is to display the number of managers from each town. So far i have this code:

```
SELECT t.Name, COUNT(*) AS [Managers from each town] 
FROM Towns t
JOIN Addresses a
ON t.TownID = a.TownID
JOIN Employees e
ON a.AddressID = e.AddressID
GROUP BY t.Name
ORDER BY [Managers from each town] DESC
```

This query returns the number of Employees, from each town, not Managers.
If i try the second query bellow, I get something totally wrong:

```
SELECT t.Name, COUNT(*) AS [Managers from each town] 
FROM Towns t
JOIN Addresses a
ON t.TownID = a.TownID
JOIN Employees e
ON a.AddressID = e.AddressID
JOIN Employees m
ON e.ManagerID = m.ManagerID

GROUP BY t.Name
ORDER BY [Managers from each town] DESC
```

Here is the structure of 'Employees' table:

EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName, MiddleName, JobTitle,DepartamentID, ManagerID, HireDate, Salary, AddressID

The correct query must return this result set:

```
Town          | Managers from each town
Issaquah      | 3
Kenmore       | 5
Monroe        | 2
Newport Hills | 1
```

Comment: Sample data would be very helpful, as would a SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following variation on your original query should could the managers who reside in each town:

```
SELECT t.Name, COUNT(DISTINCT e.EmployeeId) AS [Managers from each town]
FROM Towns t JOIN
      Addresses a
      ON t.TownID = a.TownID JOIN
      Employees e
      ON a.AddressID = e.AddressID
WHERE e.EmployeeId IN (SELECT e2.ManagerId FROM Employees e2)
GROUP BY t.Name
ORDER BY [Managers from each town] DESC;
```

The `DISTINCT` may not be necessary, but it is hard to say without better understanding the data structure.

Comment: Using this filter
WHERE e.EmployeeId IN (SELECT e2.ManagerId FROM Employees e2)
I get the proper results. Maybe Adding once again all employess to themselves is not a correct decision.. Like here:
JOIN Employees e
ON a.AddressID = e.AddressID
JOIN Employees m
ON e.ManagerID = m.ManagerID
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your structure correctly, the only indication an Employee is a manager is if its id is used as managerid for other employees. Your first query already correctly displays the count, then all that is needed is to filter the results with something like

```
where EmployeeID in (select ManagerID from Employees)
```

therefore turning your first query into :

```
SELECT t.Name, COUNT(*) AS [Managers from each town] FROM Towns t
JOIN Addresses a
ON t.TownID = a.TownID
JOIN Employees e
ON a.AddressID = e.AddressID
where EmployeeID in (select ManagerID from Employees)
GROUP BY t.Name
ORDER BY [Managers from each town] DESC
```

Comment: Your answer helped me improving my SQL code, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select t.name,
       count(*) as num_managers
  from employees m
  join addresses a
    on m.addressid = a.addressid
  join towns t
    on a.townid = t.townid
 where exists (select 1 from employees x where x.managerid = m.employeeid)
 group by t.name
 order by 2 desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query to get your required output...

```
select t.TownName, COUNT(*) as No from Town t
Inner Join Address a on a.TownID = t.TownID
inner join Employee e on e.ManagerID = a.EmployeeID
Group By t.TownName
```